# Outlook Preview Pane Not Working - Neither is Opening the Email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, preview

When I opened my Outlook today, the preview pane isn't working correctly (it previews nothing). I have logged out, logged in, reinstalled the program and still it isn't working correctly. Even when I open the email it isn't displaying the body of the email...nothing. Help!!

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of the following question: [How do I fix Outlook only showing the first line of every message?](https://superuser.com/questions/1648424/how-do-i-fix-outlook-only-showing-the-first-line-of-every-message)

Comment: As I know, Microsoft team has recognized this issue, we could follow this twitter to get more update: https://twitter.com/MSFT365Status/status/1392208966231355392